# .NET anonymous types changed to standard objects

Tags: .net, anonymous-types

I've noticed that anonymous types are boxed into standard objects when they are passed between threads.

Why is that? I've read that they are supposed to be local.

Comment: Any value has to be converted to *object* when you pass it to a ThreadStart target method.  And they all can, very basic runtime guarantee.  An anonymous type is not a special type, it just doesn't have a name in your program.  So casting it back from the *object* argument is going to be a bit disappointing.  You could cast it to *dynamic* and let the DLR figure it out.  "Supposed to be local" is of course good advice, especially when the threaded code lives in another assembly.  Just don't.

Comment: Anonymous types **are** standard types. They just don't have a name. They are plain old regular .NET reference-type objects. If I to `GetType()` on one I just created I get this `FullName`: `<>f__AnonymousType0'2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`. The `IsClass` property is `true` & the `IsValueType` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous types **are** standard types. They just don't have a name. They are plain old regular .NET reference-type objects. They don't get boxed when passed as parameters.

If I run this code:

```
var x = new { A = 5, B = "Hello" };

Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().FullName);
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().IsClass);
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().IsValueType);
```

...I get this output:

```
f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
True
False
```

Anonymous types are classes, not value types, so are not boxed.

If you do pass one to a method and you want to get it back to a strongly-type anonymous object then you can do this:

```
public T Rehydrate<T>(object anonymous, T prototype)
{
    return (T)anonymous;
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
var x = new { A = 5, B = "Hello" };

var y = (object)x;

var z = Rehydrate(x, new { A = 0, B = "" });

Console.WriteLine(z.A);
Console.WriteLine(z.B);
```

I get the following output:

```
5
Hello
```

The `prototype` parameter in the `Rehydrate` must have the same property names, the same property types, and in the same order, as the `anonymous` parameter for this to work. If you own both sides of the code - caller and callee - then that's not a problem.